# How to understand this way to add a define in C?

Tags: c

I am reading source at **openssl**, and the following lines apparently defines `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3` if it is not defined yet. Never saw such magic before. Can anyone teach me the syntax here?

```
#if !defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL3)
    | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3
#endif
```

You can reference [this link](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=ssl/s23_clnt.c;h=86ab3de1c1236ec0959df7e8eddfb988da2d1b24;hb=refs/heads/OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable) for full file and see line 327.

Comment: See line 325, this `#if` just adds some flag to the `mask` variable declared there.

Comment: _and the following lines apparently defines..._ No! These lines do not define anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So I get -1 for silly question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question makes sense only with the surrounding code (slightly simplified here):

```
    mask =  SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1|SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1
#if !defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL3)
                  |SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3
#endif
    ;
```

The preprocessor just does textual substitution. So if the preprocessor macro `OPENSSL_NO_SSL3` is not defined, the preprocessed code will look like this:

```
    mask =  SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1|SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1
                  |SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3
    ;
```

otherwise the preprocessed code ill look like this:

```
    mask =  SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1|SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't define a macro. It adds an expression to a bitmask. That operation there is bitwise or. The macro/enum `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3` must exist for it to be valid code.

If the macro `OPENSSL_NO_SSL3` **is defined**, then the code inside the conditional isn't included in the source.

Having the preprocessor check for macro definitions is a common way to implement conditional compilation. This way the same source can be compiled under various configurations. The macros to check against can be defined in source with `#define`, passed by the build system (like with the gcc `-D` option), or be builtin to the preprocessor (such as `__STDC_IEC_559__`).